# dynamic string concatenation in C

Tags: c, concatenation

I know this is a very common question, but I would like to know your thoughts about the following function. The idea is that this function can concatenate strings without worrying of the result size:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TAM 15 

char* concat(char* answer, char* src, unsigned int* limit, unsigned int* total)
{
 unsigned int length = strlen(src);

 if((*limit - *total) > length)
  strcat(answer, src); 
 else
 {
  *limit *= 2;
  answer = realloc(answer, sizeof(char)*(*limit));
  printf("RESIZING...\n");
  if(answer == NULL)
  {  
   printf("RESIZING ERROR...\n"); 
   return NULL;
  }

  strcat(answer, src); 
 }

 *total += length;

 return answer;
}

int main(void)
{
 char* strings[] = { "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE" };

 unsigned int LIMIT = TAM;   //<------
 unsigned int total = 0;     //<------

 char* mem_block = calloc(LIMIT, sizeof(char));

 unsigned int i;
 for(i = 0; i<5; ++i)
  mem_block = concat(mem_block, strings[i], &LIMIT, &total);  //<------

 printf("RES : %s -- %d\n", mem_block, strlen(mem_block));

 free(mem_block);

 return 0;  
}
```

This example runs well and valgrind reports all fine:

```
elias@elias-VirtualBox ~/Desktop $ valgrind ./reSize2
==2939== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2939== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2939== Using Valgrind-3.6.1-Debian and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2939== Command: ./reSize2
==2939== 
RESIZING...
RES : ONETWOTHREEFOURFIVE -- 19
==2939== 
==2939== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2939==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2939==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 45 bytes allocated
==2939== 
==2939== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==2939== 
==2939== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2939== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 11 from 6)
```

But there are a couple of things I don't like. I don't like to have to pass this variables //<---- to the function. Is there a better way to do it? And also if I don't receive back the return pointer "mem_block", valgrind outputs the following:

```
==2923== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2923== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2923== Using Valgrind-3.6.1-Debian and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2923== Command: ./reSize2
==2923== 
RESIZING...
==2923== Invalid read of size 1
==2923==    at 0x4028D51: strcat (mc_replace_strmem.c:176)
==2923==    by 0x8048523: concat (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923==    by 0x8048624: main (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923==  Address 0x41ca028 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 15 free'd
==2923==    at 0x402896C: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525)
==2923==    by 0x8048546: concat (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923==    by 0x8048624: main (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923== 
==2923== Invalid read of size 1
==2923==    at 0x4028D59: strcat (mc_replace_strmem.c:176)
==2923==    by 0x8048523: concat (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923==    by 0x8048624: main (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923==  Address 0x41ca029 is 1 bytes inside a block of size 15 free'd
==2923==    at 0x402896C: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525)
==2923==    by 0x8048546: concat (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923==    by 0x8048624: main (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923== 
==2923== Invalid write of size 1
==2923==    at 0x4028D6F: strcat (mc_replace_strmem.c:176)
==2923==    by 0x8048523: concat (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923==    by 0x8048624: main (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923==  Address 0x41ca033 is 11 bytes inside a block of size 15 free'd
==2923==    at 0x402896C: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525)
==2923==    by 0x8048546: concat (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923==    by 0x8048624: main (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923== 
==2923== Invalid write of size 1
==2923==    at 0x4028D7C: strcat (mc_replace_strmem.c:176)
==2923==    by 0x8048523: concat (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923==    by 0x8048624: main (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923==  Address 0x41ca035 is 13 bytes inside a block of size 15 free'd
==2923==    at 0x402896C: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525)
==2923==    by 0x8048546: concat (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923==    by 0x8048624: main (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923== 
==2923== Invalid write of size 1
==2923==    at 0x4028D81: strcat (mc_replace_strmem.c:176)
==2923==    by 0x8048523: concat (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923==    by 0x8048624: main (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923==  Address 0x41ca037 is 0 bytes after a block of size 15 free'd
==2923==    at 0x402896C: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525)
==2923==    by 0x8048546: concat (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923==    by 0x8048624: main (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923== 
==2923== Invalid read of size 1
==2923==    at 0x804864A: main (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923==  Address 0x41ca028 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 15 free'd
==2923==    at 0x402896C: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525)
==2923==    by 0x8048546: concat (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923==    by 0x8048624: main (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923== 
==2923== Invalid read of size 1
==2923==    at 0x408A75C: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1629)
==2923==    by 0x4092C9E: printf (printf.c:35)
==2923==    by 0x405F112: (below main) (libc-start.c:226)
==2923==  Address 0x41ca028 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 15 free'd
==2923==    at 0x402896C: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525)
==2923==    by 0x8048546: concat (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923==    by 0x8048624: main (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923== 
==2923== Invalid read of size 1
==2923==    at 0x40B374B: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.1 (fileops.c:1317)
==2923==    by 0x4092C9E: printf (printf.c:35)
==2923==    by 0x405F112: (below main) (libc-start.c:226)
==2923==  Address 0x41ca036 is 14 bytes inside a block of size 15 free'd
==2923==    at 0x402896C: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525)
==2923==    by 0x8048546: concat (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923==    by 0x8048624: main (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923== 
==2923== Invalid read of size 1
==2923==    at 0x40B375F: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.1 (fileops.c:1317)
==2923==    by 0x408A734: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1629)
==2923==    by 0x4092C9E: printf (printf.c:35)
==2923==    by 0x405F112: (below main) (libc-start.c:226)
==2923==  Address 0x41ca035 is 13 bytes inside a block of size 15 free'd
==2923==    at 0x402896C: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525)
==2923==    by 0x8048546: concat (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923==    by 0x8048624: main (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923== 
==2923== Invalid read of size 1
==2923==    at 0x40B36E8: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.1 (fileops.c:1349)
==2923==    by 0x408A734: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1629)
==2923==    by 0x4092C9E: printf (printf.c:35)
==2923==    by 0x405F112: (below main) (libc-start.c:226)
==2923==  Address 0x41ca028 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 15 free'd
==2923==    at 0x402896C: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525)
==2923==    by 0x8048546: concat (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923==    by 0x8048624: main (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923== 
==2923== Invalid read of size 1
==2923==    at 0x40B36F4: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.1 (fileops.c:1348)
==2923==    by 0x408A734: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1629)
==2923==    by 0x4092C9E: printf (printf.c:35)
==2923==    by 0x405F112: (below main) (libc-start.c:226)
==2923==  Address 0x41ca02a is 2 bytes inside a block of size 15 free'd
==2923==    at 0x402896C: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525)
==2923==    by 0x8048546: concat (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923==    by 0x8048624: main (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923== 
RES : ONETWOTHREEFIVE -- 15
==2923== Invalid free() / delete / delete[]
==2923==    at 0x4027C02: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:366)
==2923==    by 0x8048677: main (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923==  Address 0x41ca028 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 15 free'd
==2923==    at 0x402896C: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525)
==2923==    by 0x8048546: concat (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923==    by 0x8048624: main (in /home/elias/Desktop/reSize2)
==2923== 
==2923== 
==2923== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2923==     in use at exit: 30 bytes in 1 blocks
==2923==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 45 bytes allocated
==2923== 
==2923== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2923==    definitely lost: 30 bytes in 1 blocks
==2923==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2923==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2923==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2923==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2923== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==2923== 
==2923== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2923== ERROR SUMMARY: 80 errors from 12 contexts (suppressed: 11 from 6)
```

I'm a bit confused with this because I thought this was not necessary because  the function directly modifies the pointers.

Any comments on how to improve this function will be welcome.

Thanks a lot, and sorry for the long post.

Comment: Maybe this should be asked on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?  It would probably be 'cleaner' to group the three parameters (current pointer, allocated length, used length) into a structure and pass a pointer to the structure to the function.  Otherwise, it is just a bit too messy to use for comfort.  Look up the [Better String Library](http://bstring.sourceforge.net/) for example.

Comment: The 'invalid write' problems occur when the space is reallocated and moves; when the space grows, `realloc()` logically allocates new space and copies the old data to the new space, and releases the old space.  The old pointer is not guaranteed to be valid, so you must use the returned value.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I didn't knew of the "CodeReview" section. I'll used it next time :) and thanks for your good explanation about realloc.

Comment: Unfortunately, any scheme that employs `realloc` creates the danger than you will mistakenly have another copy of the source pointer somewhere and attempt to use it after this operation.  It's not really possible to create a "carefree" function of this sort (though certainly your general scheme can *reduce* the amount of care needed somewhat).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you modify answer in your function you *only* modify it in the scope of the function, the calling function will still see the old value (which is invalid since you called realloc).

When you return the new pointer and start using it in the calling function everything works, as it should.

The easiest way to fix this is to make your concat function look like:

```
void concat(char** answer, char* src, unsigned int* limit, unsigned int* total) {
if((*limit - *total) > length)
  strcat(*answer, src); 
 else
 {
  *limit *= 2;
  *answer = realloc(*answer, sizeof(char)*(*limit));
  printf("RESIZING...\n");
  if(*answer == NULL)
  {  
   printf("RESIZING ERROR...\n"); 
   return NULL;
  }

  strcat(*answer, src); 
 }

 *total += length;
}
```

and call it like:

```
concat(&mem_block, strings[i], &LIMIT, &total);
```

However, you should abstract out your strings into their own type instead of manually passing their lengths together. Something like:

```
typedef struct _dynamic_string {
    char *s;
    unsigned int capacity;
    unsigned int length;
} dynamic_string;
```

should be a good starting point, then you can start to implement dynamic functions using this struct instead.

Comment: This code leaks: realloc don't free memory on failure.

Comment: This is true, however: 1. it is the answer to the question asked (just a small modification to the given code sample) and 2. realloc fails if you've triggered an out-of-memory condition, if that has happened memory leaks don't really matter anymore since you probably won't be able to recover from it and 3. really depends on the semantics of the concat-function, do you always want it to free the old string if the concat-operation fails?

Comment: 3. this code rewrite pointer `*answer` to `NULL`, so it likely needs to delete the string. Yes, I know this leak presents in original code, I just wanted to expand your answer.

Comment: That's true, It's been a long time since I answered the question, so I guess I forgot about it. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you check if the `limit * 2` expression is lower than the the current limit + `length`? If so, you would need to increase the limit. Otherwise I think you could force a buffer overflow.

I think you have to pass the variables you mentioned as pointers, because they will get edited in some cases. A possible alternative that is semantically the same but syntatically "easier" might be to define a `struct string`:

```
struct string {
    char* buffer;
    int limit;
    int total;
};
```

And this could be used to abstract away all of the info representing a string.

As for the `mem_block` problem, you have to receive it, because as per [realloc documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/):

```
The function may move the memory block to a new location, in which case the new location is returned.
```

So it may happen that the string address passed as a parameter may actually not be the same as the one returned. You can fix it by passing a pointer to a pointer as the argument, so when it changes you can update it in place:

```
void concat(char** answer, char* src, unsigned int* limit, unsigned int* total) {
    /* When using strcat: */
    strcat(*answer, src);

    /* When reallocating */
    *answer = realloc(*answer, *limit);
            /* Also, sizeof(char) is always 1, by definition */

    /* ... */
}
```

Hope this helps =)

Comment: I think you are write, I need to check that to avoid problems. THANKS!!