# How to build Url dynamically in C

Tags: c, string, url, dynamic-memory-allocation

I need to build an url in with Query Params and different API Endpoints. I don't like to use a char array with a fixed sized because memory is wasted and I rely on hoping that the size will be big enough.

```c
#define BASE_URL  "https//mydomain.com/api/"
#define ID "ID1"

char* do_endpoint_request(const char* param)
{
   char url[500];
   snprintf(url, sizeof(url), BASE_URL "endpoint?id=%s&param1=%s", ID, param);
   // do request with url ...

}
```

How can I improve this code, that memory is allocated dynamically with exact size of the string and params injected?

Comment: you could first call `vsnprintf( NULL, 0, ... );` It will return the size needed. Then you can ` `malloc()` the memory needed or define a VLA

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731389/dynamic-string-concatenation-in-c) is a question about dynamic string concatenation in C, with answers

Comment: Are you using `url` outside this function `do_endpoint_request()`? There's little point in creating URL on heap-memory when you've one available on stack already.

Comment: No i am not using it outside. Just in that function.

Comment: How long can the string `param` be? Are there sanity checks done before `do_endpoint_request` is called?

Comment: Param can have different sizes. There are no sanity checks yet.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt `vsnprintf` just takes one Parameter for formatting. Or am I wrong? I need two.

Comment: @Aeropagz Forget my question. I ask another one: can you ensure that the total length of the URL will never exceed 499 (or maybe much less?) characters? If yes, then your code is good enough. If the string `param` can be huge, maybe more than 1000 characters, then you might want to consider to improve your code.

Comment: In vour case it's `snprintf()` not `vsnprintf()`, sorry. So you call `snprintf()` like you do just with `NULL` instead of `url` and `0` instead of `sizeof url` and store the result. Then you create `url` with an appropriate size and call the final `snprintf()` (or just `sprintf()` as url is now guaranteed t be large enough).

Comment: I've made it an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the fact that `snprintf()` may be called with NULL instead of an actual buffer and that it returns the length of the string that would have been created if there was enough space. So:

```
#define BASE_URL  "https//mydomain.com/api/"
#define ID "ID1"

char* do_endpoint_request(const char* param)
{
   int len;

   len = snprintf(NULL, 0, BASE_URL "endpoint?id=%s&param1=%s", ID, param);    
   char url[len+1]; // len excludes NULL; use malloc() if you can't use VLA
   // sprintf() is ok now, url is guaranteed to be large enough
   sprintf(url, BASE_URL "endpoint?id=%s&param1=%s", ID, param);
   // do request with url ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Glad we could help. You might want to look at the remarks in @jabberwocky's answer too. He is absolutely right

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
char* do_endpoint_request(const char* param)
{
   int sizeneeded = snprintf(NULL, 0, BASE_URL "endpoint?id=%s&param1=%s", ID, param);

   char url[sizeneeded + 1];
   sprintf(url, BASE_URL "endpoint?id=%s&param1=%s", ID, param);

   // do request with url ...
}
```

But if the string `param` is of "reasonable" size, a local variable like in your example is good enough.

However you probably should do a sanity check on `param`, to ensure that it's length is of reaonable/plausible size. Otherways all methods might end up in undefined behaviour:

- in your original code: if `param` is too long, the `url` array will be too small and you'll get undefined behaviour.
- in the code suggested in this answer: if `param` is too long (maybe longer that a few thousands, depends on your platform and other factors), `char url[sizeneeded];` might not end well and you'll get undefined behaviour.

Comment: Also thank you. Are there any disadvantages to use snprintf right away? I am C beginner and feel bad to use fixed size arrays at all for strings. Are they really a thing in "professional" C code ?

Comment: @Aeropagz it depends. If you can ensure that the final URL will fit into your local variable, and your fixed size local variable is not huge (say several thousands, depnds on your platform etc.), then your code is OK.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, this code runs on an ESP32 so it is probably the best to save memory everywhere I can.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, we would need the size of the parameter.

```c
char* do_endpoint_request(const char* param, int param_size)
{
   char* url = calloc(param_size + <size of base url>, sizeof(char));
   snprintf(url, sizeof(url), BASE_URL "endpoint?id=%s&param1=%s", ID, param);
   // do request with url ...

}
```

Something such as this should work as it but the allocated size might need to be changed.

Comment: And what about freeing the allocated memory?? And why do you need `param_size` which is not in the original code and which is not needed anyway?